# Error in playing some type of audio file in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I would like to play audio Files from the directory in swift and I use following code for initializing:

```
func setAVAudioPlayer(){
                let fileName = URL(string: audioFilename)?.lastPathComponent
                let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myPath)
                let destinationPath = fileURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName!)
                let filePath = destinationPath?.path
                let fileManager : FileManager = FileManager.default
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!){
                    
                    ChannelViewController.audioPlayerArrayList[indexPathRow] = AVAudioPlayer()
                    let path: String! = myPath + "/" + fileName!
                    let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                    do
                    {
                        ChannelViewController.audioPlayerArrayList[indexPathRow] = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: mp3URL as URL)
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        print("An error occurred while trying to extract audio file")
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                }
        
    }
```

It works for some audio type like m4a, mp3, etc. but I get error for some type like 3gp files.
How can I fix this issue and this function works for all audio type.

Error:

```
2020-11-29 10:16:57.828589+0330 School_iApp[4038:63911] 3531:  MP4Parser_PacketProvider->GetASBD() failed
2020-11-29 10:16:57.829053+0330 School_iApp[4038:63911] 101:  OpenFromDataSource failed
2020-11-29 10:16:57.829252+0330 School_iApp[4038:63911] 76:  Open failed
An error occurred while trying to extract audio file
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) says AVAudioPlayer supports all audio formats supported by iOS and macOS. I don't know what OS you're working with, but [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX.html) is a list of supported formats on macOS. That reference looks like it's probably out of date, but maybe you can find something more current elsewhere, and see if the formats you're interested in are listed.

Comment: @scg thanks, it doesn't support 3gp.I have to convert it to another format.

Comment: I am getting this error with a plain mp3 file encoded with lame (ffmpeg) with Swift 5.5.  It started with Swift 5.4 for me.

Answer (score -1):

AVAudioPlayer is a Audio player your tried to play a mp4 data that’s a video. That will not work. But there is a way in AvFoundation to take the audio from a Video.
Here is something to read for you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos